# How to change the sitecore password if the password expiration code is implemented in sitecore 9.1

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-commerce, xconnect, sitecore-forms

Implemented sitecore user password expiration code but not able to reset the password of that user. Please let me know the way to reset the sitecore password.